# SQL Last working day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, dateadd, getdate

I have the following query

```
select Case.casekey, LoginName, startdatedate, SenttoClientDate
from case with (nolock)
where SenttoClientDate = dateadd(day,-1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

This returns results where {senttoclientdate} = yesterday.

The problem is that if I run this on a Monday I will get Sunday's results, but I want last working day's. So if I run on a Monday, I want the Friday's results.

Comment: try CASE and WEEKDAY

Comment: What's the expected result if you run the query on a Sunday?

Comment: what if it's Tues. and Mon. was a holiday?  You'll need a table of working days for this, with your holidays/whatever excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
WHERE SenttoClientDate = (SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a case on the datepart

```
where SentToClientDate = 
    case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 then dateadd(day,-3,getdate()) -- Monday is day 2, for no reason whatsoever
         else dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In where condition use casing as below,

```
    select Case.casekey, LoginName, startdatedate, SenttoClientDate
    from case with (nolock)
    where SentToClientDate = 
    case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 then dateadd(day,-3,getdate())
         when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 1 then dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
         else dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this, it's very simple and perfect solution:

```
SELECT  Case.casekey, LoginName, startdatedate, SenttoClientDate
FROM case with (nolock)
WHERE SenttoClientDate = 
CAST(DATEADD(dd, 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) = 6 THEN  0 
    ELSE (6-(DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE())+7)) END, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```